# Append data in realtime to an empty pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I'd like to add some data, in realtime, to an empty DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'price'])   # this is a simple example
                                               # but in my code, I have more 
                                               # columns: 'volume', etc.
for i in range(5):                             # here it lasts one day in my real use case
    time.sleep(2)
    t = pd.datetime.now()
    df[t] = 5 + i
    # here I need to have access to the latest updates of df

print df
```

The output is:

```
Empty DataFrame  
Columns: [time, price, 2015-12-27 01:55:29.812000, 2015-12-27 01:55:31.812000, 2015-12-27 01:55:33.812000, 2015-12-27 01:55:35.812000, 2015-12-27 01:55:37.812000]  
Index: []
```

whereas I wanted:

```
time                                price
2015-12-27 01:55:29.812000          5
2015-12-27 01:55:31.812000          6
2015-12-27 01:55:33.812000          7
...
```

**How to append data to a DataFrame like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing into the DataFrame into column t with `df[t]`. I think you would like to index into it by row instead.

From the looks of it though, it appears a Series may be better suited since you are updating by a time index.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

series = pd.Series()

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    t = pd.datetime.now()
    series[t] = 5 + i

print series


import pandas as pd
import time
```

In the case that a dataframe is needed, it can be appended using `df.ix[row_index]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1', 'col2'])

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    t = pd.datetime.now() # Generate row index
    df.ix[t] = {'col1': 5 + i, 'col2': 20 + i}


print df
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really need a DataFrame (because I have several columns)

Comment: Added an example for that. To append a single row using an index.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using pandas' [append()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) function to migrate lists of your looped data to dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'price'])

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    t = pd.datetime.now()
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'time': [t],
                                 'price': [5 + i]}))
print df
```

Comment: This is not possible because in reality my `for`  loop is much longer than `range(5)`  (its duration is 1 day) and I need to be able to access to the *updated DataFrame* inside the loop. I added some comments in my code in original question.

Comment: See update. Still same concept but instead of appending to lists in loop and then a bulk append to df out of loop, each iteration appends to df in loop.

Comment: Did the update work for your needs? Please do accept if my solution helped you.